# Can we use a ADSL2+ modem in bridged mode to convert to ethernet WAN?

Tags: router, internet, ethernet, modem, adsl

I am no networking master, so I have no clue if this makes sense.

I have a DSL line from my internet provider with all the service details. Now, I have a TP-Link modem (+router) WD8961N. This is currently running in PPPoE mode. Works perfectly.

My question is this: say I want to use pfSense on an old PC. I have installed the new PCI cards for WiFi and Ethernet. To do that, if I switch the mode of my TP-Link modem to "Bridge", then connect the PC with the router using an ethernet cable and configure the PPPoE settings on my PC, will the internet work? As in, is the configuration correct if I want to use my PC as a WiFi router?

My understanding of the bridged mode is that it removes all of the PPP login stuff and tells the router connected to it to do that.

Am I right? Will this work? Any insight is appreciated?

Comment: So, again, why do I have a downvote? Care to explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, bridged mode + PPPoE on a pfSense box should work fine.

One notable caveat to test though is that some ISPs who use PPPoE have an MTU blackhole and don't set PPP MTU (some Cisco client equipment fails to negotiate the PPP session if the far end tries to set MTU) and also don't themselves clamp TCP MSS to work around this.

Setting your PPP MTU manually to 1492, or even 1480 (I've seen extreme cases where even lower is needed, although not recently), or enabling TCP MSS clamping works around this client side.

Comment: So I get everything right! ;) Thanks a lot for that "silent error". Coming from a programming background, I know how bad it feels when you're banging your head on the keyboard because JS automatically inserted that extra semicolon.